# icoMoon fonts setup, icons not showing up

Tags: css, icon-fonts

I am not able to display my icon fonts. This is the directory structure I have:

_ folder containing 
  css and fonts folders
outside of the _ folder I have the demo1.html page

This is the code I am using for setting up the fonts:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'icomoon';
    src:url('_/fonts/icomoon.eot?-9hqo51');
    src:url('_/fonts/icomoon.eot?#iefix-9hqo51') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('_/fonts/icomoon.woff?-9hqo51') format('woff'),
        url('_/fonts/icomoon.ttf?-9hqo51') format('truetype'),
        url('_/fonts/icomoon.svg?-9hqo51#icomoon') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

The html code is the following:

```
<span aria-hidden="true" class="icon-raja_head"></span>
```

Here is a [sample](http://gladahundar01.businesscatalyst.com/demo1.html) page I set up. The code for the fonts are on line 903 in my stylesheet.

Thanks
-Sohail

Comment: Strangely, it works if I move the css file outside _ folder and on the same level as the .html file and keep the fonts folder under the _ folder.

Comment: But I don't want to move my css file to make that to work though

Comment: I wonder if this is a path issue. This http://gladahundar01.businesscatalyst.com/demo2.html has the css on the same level as the html file and the fonts folder as previously in the _ folder. The sample works on my local machine but but not on the web

Comment: In the console I am getting File Not Found errors, for the woff, ttf and the svg file, for example: 

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (ERROR: The file requested could not be found.) http://gladahundar01.businesscatalyst.com/_/css/_/fonts/icomoon.svg?-9hqo51#icomoon

The path in the error message for those files doesn't seem to correspond with my path. My loccal path is: _/fonts/icomoon.svg

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your src reference is relative so your css delclaration is looking for fonts in a directory called `_` within your `_` directory. This is why it works form the root directory.

You need either correct the relative path to `'fonts/icomoon.eot?-9hqo51'` or make the path absolute by preceding it with `/` eg: `'/_/fonts/icomoon.eot?-9hqo51'`